# Software architecture tradeoffs?

Tags: architecture, software-design

I'm trying to get into Solution Architecture and come from a non-technical background. As such, I'm trying to educate myself more on architectural tradeoffs.

Would people be able to give me a brief overview of architectural tradeoffs engineers normally have to discuss?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the following topics to educate yourself on architectural tradeoffs:-

1. CAP Theorem
2. Definitions of Availability, Reliability, Consistency, Fault Tolerance, Performance and Time Complexity
3. Difference between Cloud computing, On-premise and Hybrid
4. SAAS applications vs Desktop based applications
5. Types of Databases and Data stores - Relational, No-SQL, Object Store, File Stores